# mysql will make more connections than allowed

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I'm using Sequelize ORM for my nodejs project and it seems there is a mistake in configuration or I'm doing something really awry with the queries... The problem is that our client will make more than 60 connections sometimes when the user is requesting a lot of information at once (graphql request with deep structure and data loaders on top for a lot of records fetched from MySQL). The pool settings should not let do that since it is configured for 10 max connections at once. The main question is how those connections appear? The app is being hosted at AWS using ELB, for MySQL we are using RDS and we can have up to 2 app instances at once, so no more than 20 connections at all. Sequelize config:

```
production: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    define: {
      charset: 'utf8mb4',
      collate: 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    },
    pool: {
      max: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_SIZE, 10), // 10 from ENV variables
      min: 0,
      acquire: 60000,
      idle: 60000,
    },
    operatorsAliases: 0,
    logging: false,
  },
```

once there are >50 connections on our RDS client we can see that our ELB can't perform health check since it can't make new connections and return positive status from MySQL. so our app becomes unreachable.

After bombing the backend with this particular query I've fetched processlist for MySQL. Some sleeping queries will go to more than 1000 "time".

[image: queries]

Also I'm going to attach my Sequelize connection config. It is a singleton object which will be run only once the app is loaded. But on the other hand, I'm importing models from this file everywhere in the project. But is it a mistake?

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-cycle */
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import databaseConfig from '#config/database';
import models from './models';

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const database = (databaseConfig as any)[env];

const sequelize = new Sequelize(database.database, database.username, database.password, {
  host: database.host,
  dialect: database.dialect,
  define: database.define,
  pool: database.pool,
  operatorsAliases: database.operatorsAliases,
  logging: database.logging,
  retry: {
    match: [
      /SequelizeConnectionError/,
      /SequelizeConnectionRefusedError/,
      /SequelizeHostNotFoundError/,
      /SequelizeHostNotReachableError/,
      /SequelizeInvalidConnectionError/,
      /SequelizeConnectionTimedOutError/,
    ],
    max: Infinity,
  },
});

sequelize.addModels(Object.values(models));

setTimeout(() => console.log('Waiting for mysql connection...'), 200);
sequelize.sync().then(() => console.log('Mysql connection established'));

export const {
 ... 16 MODELS...
} = models;

export { sequelize, Sequelize };
```

also I'm using sequelize suggested config in `.sequelizerc` file to make a connection when running migrations etc..

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('dist', './config/database.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('dist', './models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('dist', './seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('dist', './migrations')
}
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Weird. What happens if you omit the `max:` line from your `pool:` object? What do you see if you give the command `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`  from a MySQL client program?  You may have to log in to MySQL before your connections run amok to see that.  Please [edit] your question.

Comment: dumb question - is the connection pool a singleton object?  Is it possible more than one connection pool is being generated - e.g if you're running a webserver that spawns multiple processes rather than a single multithreaded process?

Comment: @O.Jones if I don't write `max:` in my config, it will give me the default number which is `5`.  Now I've updated the question with this default max connections number which is 5 and attached a process list which was printed in the middle of "bombing|"

Comment: That's not a dumb question at all @mcfinnigan coz sometimes that might be a problem hehe. Anyway, I've edited my question and added a little more explanation of how I'm using this orm.

Comment: Is it possible for the application code to bypass the connection pool management? I am not particularly familiar with the MySQL library but I would guess rogue code could just be creating new connections instead of requesting a pooled connection from the pool manager.

Comment: I'm not sure and I would likely be against this expression since the ORM was built with this config and the main rule with the description is to set pool settings in this case. So I would say no, but I might be missing something. I believe that might be a problem with the code itself or the config since I can't find any information on internet with the same case "sequelize more connections than allowed"

Comment: In Nodejs I understand the require() does not guarantee singleton instances of the same module. I have had situations in which the same module is loaded multiple times in different parts of the code. I will try to find where this happened previously and how we worked around it.

Comment: From your `SHOW PROCESSLIST` display I count (I think) nine distinct IP addresses in your connection list. Some are from "staging" and others from "development". It looks like you might be using up your RDS connections on various "rogue" (that is, run from developer laptops) clients.  Maybe you should put your dev and staging clients on a separate RDS instance? Or maybe dev clients should use max:2 for their connection pools?

Comment: Slightly off topic ... using the same database username/password for development data and staging/production data is a *terrible* idea. You could hit the database with broken development code and, by mistake, corrupt, delete, or exfiltrate your customers' data.

Comment: Further to my comment about singleton module load not being guaranteed: The situation we encountered was because MS Windows is not case-sensitive, but the `require()` function _is_ case sensitive. So,, using `const xxx = require( "./xxx" )` in one place and `const xxx = require("./XXX");` in another in the same folder will load two copies of the same module. Not sure if this applies to you but you have to be careful about using consistent, correct case of module names in Windows-based nodejs.

Comment: Good point from @O.Jones , also note that there are (I think) max 5 connections from each IP address.